# Long Lost series of books read in school

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I read a series of books in high school about the Earth being invaded by more technologically advanced race of aliens (aren't they all? But of course if they weren't then it wouldn't be much of a story) where we seemed to fight a fairly futile war.

It was set in the future - in London I'm pretty sure - as we were using "laser rifles" but the fight suddenly turned in our favour when we realised their full body shielding, while being impervious to laser fire was in fact highly vulnerable to solid objects:  projectile weapons like pistols and rifles.  This is identified when the protagonist watches a bunch of alien soldiers being injured by the rubble from a collapsing bridge.

Anyone know this?

Comment: When were you in high school? Do you remember anything about the protagonist (male/female/young/old)? Do you remember anything about the aliens (description/name)? Do you remember any specific words or phrases used in the book?

Comment: I don't remember much but it was very well written...   He was a young man like senior high school age and i think he had an action girl http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ActionGirl running around with him.   Up until he sees the bridge collapsing leaving the shield toting aliens limping away bleeding and dying the story has quite the hopeless feel.   As in all is lost.  But then afterward we kick arse!

Comment: Still haven't answered when you were in high school. Also, was this a US English edition? Paperback? Do you remember anything about the cover perhaps?

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, I suggest trying [BookSleuth](http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/abesleuthcom?redirCnt=1&=) over at AbeBooks. There are a lot of used-and-rare booksellers in there who have an economic incentive to answer questions like this one correctly in the hopes you'll buy a copy from them.

Comment: @Donald.McLean yes you are right.   High school was 85 to 91.   It was quite British and I remember locations like the Thames being mentioned.  If was paperback edition.

Answer (score 6):

It's been nearly ten years but I figure I can give an answer to this one. The OP is most likely seeking the Hood's Army series by Nathan Elliot (pseud. for Christopher Evans).

The time frame matches (1986) and it is a very British book trilogy. The series revolves around the invasion of Earth by advanced aliens who are ultimately defeated by a rag-tag team of humans wielding very primitive weapons. In fact, the more primitive, the more effective.

Sadly, there is very little online about the books but from this review of the second in the series, you can get several connections:

> But is it really possible for such a small band of soldiers with their primitive weapons to defeat the sophisticated aliens? With Hood in charge, there is a chance.

https://sfbook.com/earth-invaded.htm

And from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Evans_(author)):

> The Hood's Army trilogy is a series of young adult science fiction novels by Evans, but written under the pseudonym of "Nathan Elliott." The trilogy was published in 1986.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pytam.png) The books that make up the series are entitled Earth Invaded; Slaveworld; and The Liberators. They tell of a near future in which Earth is conquered by an alien race named the K'Thraa, and of the resistance force which battles them.

[image: second book]